# AffirmPaymentController Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sap-commerce-cloud

Below is the method that I have

```
@RequestMapping(value =  "/authorise", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
   public String authorise(@RequestParam(name = "checkout_token", required = false) final String checkoutToken,
         final Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectModel) {

      boolean success = false;

      try
      {
         success = affirmPaymentFacade.authorisePayment(checkoutToken);
      }
      catch (RuntimeException re)
      {
         LOG.warn("error during payment authorisation ", re);
      }
      if(success){
         final OrderData orderData;
         try
         {
            orderData = getCheckoutFacade().placeOrder();
         }
         catch (final Exception e)
         {
            LOG.error("Failed to place Order", e);
            //TODO-BE auth reversal
            //GlobalMessages.addErrorMessage(model, "checkout.affirm.order.failed");
            return REDIRECT_PREFIX + CHECKOUT_AFFIRM_ERROR;
         }

         return redirectToOrderConfirmationPage(orderData);
      }else {
         //GlobalMessages.addErrorMessage(redirectModel,"checkout.affirm.authorisation.failed");
         return REDIRECT_PREFIX + CHECKOUT_AFFIRM_ERROR;
      }
   }
```

When GET request is called its working fine but when we call with POST request and request payload
checkout_token=XXXX, I am getting below error

> WARN  [hybrisHTTP24] [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
> Request method 'POST' not supported]

**EDIT**

Even I tried with removing all parameters but still no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable csrf token for this url

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a little information about better posting on StackOverflow:

- Reduce your problem to the compactest possible code (Your code in the method does not matter, if you are having problems with the routing to the method)
- This is not a hybris only problem as Spring MVC is used. You will get a lot more answers in a spring mvc forum as in a Hybris stackoverflow.
- Please include your imports

With this code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;


@RestController
public class TestController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authorise", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
    public String authorise(@RequestParam(name = "checkout_token", required = false) final String checkoutToken,
            final Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectModel)
    {
        return "authorise";
    }
}
```

}

The method is accessible by GET and POST:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9080/authorise
>> authorise

curl -X POST http://localhost:9080/authorise
>> authorise
```

Maybe you are trying to use the wrong url?